# Anti particle of neutron

Tags: quantum-mechanics, antimatter

What do we mean by anti neutron? I can understand that electron and proton have their own anti-counterparts based on their charge differences but on what basis can you say that you have an anti particle for neutron?

Comment: There is also a difference in other particle properties, like lepton and baryon numbers. See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antimatter) website.